# Help with CAML query

Tags: caml-query, content-query-web-part

I have the following query but I am not sure if it does what I really want:

```
   <Where>
      <And>
         <Contains
            <FieldRef Name='Phase' />
            <Value Type='MultiChoice'>Design</Value>
         </Contains>
         <And>
            <Contains>
               <FieldRef Name='Process' />
               <Value Type='Choice'>Blueprint</Value>
            </Contains>
            <Or>
               <Contains>
                  <FieldRef Name='Document_x0020_Type' />
                  <Value Type='Choice'>Procedure</Value>
               </Contains>
               <Or>
                  <Contains>
                     <FieldRef Name='Document_x0020_Type' />
                     <Value Type='Choice'>Policy</Value>
                  </Contains>
                  <Contains>
                     <FieldRef Name='Document_x0020_Type' />
                     <Value Type='Choice'>Template</Value>
                  </Contains>
               </Or>
            </Or>
         </And>
      </And>
   </Where>
```

I want to get all documents from a library where the

```
Phase = Design
Process = Blueprint
AND
Document type is either Procedure, Policy or Template.
```

In my first query I had Process = Start up and it gave me all the correct documents but when I changed it to Blueprint (no document has this Process as meta data yet) it returned half of all my documents.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your first contains tag is missing a ">"

Comment: You need to clarify what the filter is as its ambiguous as written. Is it Phase = Design AND Process = Blueprint AND (Document Type = Procedure OR Document Type = Policy OR Document Type = Template) ?

Comment: yes you are correct Ryan

Answer (score 3):

It migth be more efficient to use [Camlex.NET](http://camlex.codeplex.com/). It more understandable for new to SharePoint developers.

[Stramit SharePoint Caml Viewer](http://spcamlviewer.codeplex.com/) migth be helpfull if you tried to write caml by hands, nor using UI or C# code.

Comment: +1 to Camlex.NET, very cool tool.

Answer (score 1):

Always use the [U2U Caml Query builder](http://www.u2u.net/Tools/wincamlquerybuilder/CamlQueryBuilder.aspx) to test your CAML queries. Check it out.

Comment: Did you notice that your first "<Contains" tag for design does not close properly with ">". Was that a typo?

Comment: FYI.. you can edit your answer to include more info instead of posting a comment. :)

Answer (score 1):

First thing is that you're using the Contains operator and not Equals which may give strange results. - e.g. both "PolicyTemplate" and "Template" **contain** "Template" - only you can tell us if this is what you want.

That CAML breaks down to this (excuse using = in place of contains for readability)

```
Phase = Design
AND
Process = Blueprint
AND
(Document Type = Procedure OR Document Type = Policy OR Document Type = Template)
```

Which is probably what you described in your question (it's a little ambiguous as written)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
 <Where>
      <And>
         <Contains>
            <FieldRef Name='Phase' />
            <Value Type='MultiChoice'>Design</Value>
         </Contains>
         <And>
            <Contains>
               <FieldRef Name='Process' />
               <Value Type='Choice'>Blueprint</Value>
            </Contains>
            <In>
              <FieldRef Name='Document_x0020_Type' />
              <Values>
                <Value Type='Choice'>Procedure</Value>
                <Value Type='Choice'>Policy</Value>
                <Value Type='Choice'>Template</Value>
              </Values>
            </In>
         </And>
      </And>
   </Where>
```